# Android studio organize-imports, will not remove unresolved imports

Tags: java, android-studio, import

I have a class B that imports class A.

I moved class A around and reset class B, so now it points to the previous package class A was in.

Now I want, Just like in Eclipse, to press Ctrl+Shift+O, and "magically" Android Studio will remove all the unresolved imports, and will import class A from its new package.

This happens mainly because we have moved the classes in our git submodule, and want all the projects depending on that submodule, to be easily fixed...

(This is a very simplified example of the situation, we have many files that we moved around)

Ctrl+Shift+O does not work!

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio has built-in feature to remove unused import

```
Android Studio > File > Settings > Editor > Auto Import >Optimize Imports on the fly
```

Comment: In my settings *All* options there are always checked.